# What is hops in HttpClient?

Tags: http, networking, tcp, httpclient, ping

I'm learning about HttpClient, I can't understand `hops`, is it a proxy?

> HttpClient is capable of establishing connections to the target host either directly or via a route that may involve multiple intermediate connections - also referred to as hops.

Comment: Is it not just the TCP [hop count](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hop_(networking))?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hop_(networking)

Comment: A bit of false advertising there. They appear to be claiming credit for something that is built into IP.

Answer (score 0):

This refers to using multiple proxies. It is even explained in the same paragraph, two sentences later:

> The use of multiple intermediate proxies to tunnel connections to the target host is referred to as proxy chaining.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the direct route shall have one hop. There shall be two hops if the route is through a proxy. There shall be n+1 hops if the route is through a chain of n proxies.

The getHopCount shall return the number of hops in a route which shall help in giving further understanding of the same .